# Stretching a background image vertically not in scale, not just cover - Can this be accomplished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

EDIT: The answer would allow the background image to change it's height depending on the size of the body.  if the body is 500px high, it should be 100% width, 500px height.  or 100% width 2500px height.

Maybe I'm missing the boat on this, but I'm trying to figure out how to have my background image scale with the page.  The end user doesn't want for the background image to be static (COVER), but the image should scale with the bigger his content gets on his site.

I'm guessing this can't be done with CSS alone. When I say I guess I've been through a mess load of different ways of doing this.

Is this just a simple javascript/jquery where I get the height of the body tag, and then apply that to the background image height?

If you need an example:

```
<body>
<div class="first"><!--TEXT--></div>
<div class="second"><!--TEXT--></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body { background: url(http://flashfreezeicecream.com/bg.jpg) center no-repeat; }
div { width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; }
.first { height: 1000px; }
.second { height: 500px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WEat7/

This would need to work on multiple pages with different body heights

EDIT:  http://jsfiddle.net/WEat7/1/
Fixed widths on the divs to illustrate the concept.  I apologize

Comment: What should happen when a user scrolls the page? should the image be fixed to the top and occupy the whole height?

Comment: The image scrolls with the page.  So if the content of a page is only 400px high, the background image has a width of 100% and a height of 400px.

When the page has a lot of content and is 1700px high, then we need to adjust the background image height to 1700px and keep the width at 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
    background: url(http://flashfreezeicecream.com/bg.jpg) center no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WEat7/

Comment: As you can see the background image doesn't stretch to the bottom of the text in the final div
I added  a fixed width to the divs for illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/WEat7/1/

Comment: @NicholasDecker, it does :) In your fiddle the content is bigger than the values you provide so it seems not to stretch. In reality - if you cut off the overflowing content or remove the fixed heights - the background *will* stretch no matter what. see here (cut off the content) - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/WEat7/2/? or here - (remove the heights) - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/WEat7/4/

Comment: The content needs to be displayed... I can't cut it off though

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't set a height on your content div. Maybe set min-height if you want the background image to always have a minimum height for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS should fix the background image and have it cover the entire body no matter what size the width or height - see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HWWvB/)

```
body {
    background: url(http://flashfreezeicecream.com/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

However, please note that IE8 [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) `background-size`.

**Edit: [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HWWvB/3/)** using following CSS

```
body {
    background: url(http://flashfreezeicecream.com/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: The end user doesn't want for the background image to be static (COVER)

Comment: In my example. the image _will_ scale up when the window is bigger than the image. Do you also want it to scale down when the window is smaller than the image?

Comment: …which it also does. @Nicholas Decker A static position does not say anything about how you position the background. Please describe your requirements a bit clearer.

Comment: The image will scale up.  What I'm looking for is: Stretching a background image vertically not in scale, not just cover.

Regardless of width, I would like to stretch the background image vertically to allow it to fill the background regardless of what kind of content is on the site. 
Meaning if the content is taller than the background image, the background image is then full height no matter what.  Scrolls with content and doesn't sit there as a still image.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEat7/1/

Comment: I apologize, I thought I was being clear in my title.  Please forgive me.

Comment: Updated answer with CSS for a background that stretches with height, now I (think I) understand your requirements.

Comment: Where is this auto tag from in background-size.  What browsers is it compatible with?  I've never seen it before!

Comment: I've seen auto like 100% auto... but not with a comma then auto.

Comment: Sorry I was using some code from a test site I have locally that has multiple backgrounds. This is what the comma separated values would apply to. Removing the `, auto` should still allow it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your body css:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: doesn't do the job.  The background image doesn't fill vertically.

Comment: background-size:150% 150%;

Comment: Think so . If we use 'background-attachment: fixed;' it may look like a static one

Comment: That is what I want to do.. but the client wants the image to scroll.... So the image gets taller when the page gets taller, and the image gets smaller when the content is less

Comment: Sorry Dude in that case i think i cant help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we need a wrap answer ))

It has been suggested above that `background-size: 100% 100%;` will stretch the background image to the full width and the full height. And so it does.

Say your content is small (400px) - the background image will cover only 400 - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/WEat7/7/

Say your content is really huge (2500px) - the background image will still cover the full height - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/WEat7/8/

Comment: I actually told you 30 minutes ago :) When you say that a div has `height: 1000px` and put some reeealy huge content there (say 2000px) the div will remain 1000px high (but the content will flow out of it further - so the body will officially be 1000 high too - and that means that the background will stretch only for 1000 pixels. If it's OK with you, mark the accepted answer. The best candidate is DiMono ;)

Comment: I see why it works in the fiddle and not my application.  My body height isn't filling the area.  You can see in this that HTML, BODY & FORM are all at not 100% height.  I'm guessing this is my real issue.

Comment: http://www.toku-e.com/  Is a site you can see this on.  Not the actual site, but the same issue I'm having.

Comment: @Nicholas Decker I couldn't find any background on the body element on the site you provided. If you still experience any problems consider asking another question concerning this specific site. This question seems to be answered but lacks an accepted answer. Cheers.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  Thanks for your help but you just don't seem to get what I am talking about.